# Full text search using CONTAINS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

I have the following records:

```
create table ft_test1
(
    col1 int identity(1,1),
    col2 varchar(max)
);

insert into ft_test1 values('John A Henry');
insert into ft_test1 values('Dsouza mak Dee');
insert into ft_test1 values('Smith Ashla Don');

create table ft_test2
(
    col1 int identity(1,1),
    col2 varchar(max)
);

insert into ft_test2 values('Mak');
insert into ft_test2 values('McKoy Obee Zen');
insert into ft_test2 values('Henry A John');
```

FULLTEXT INDEX Setup:

Step 1: Creating unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_test1_Col1 ON ft_test1(col1);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_test2_Col1 ON ft_test2(col1);
```

Step 2: Creating Catalog

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG cat_ft
WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
```

Step 3: Creating FULLTEXT INDEX

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON ft_test1  
(col2 LANGUAGE 1033)  
KEY INDEX UIX_test1_Col1  
ON cat_ft  
WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON ft_test2  
(col2 LANGUAGE 1033)  
KEY INDEX UIX_test2_Col1  
ON cat_ft  
WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM
```

Query: I want to do `JOIN` between these two tables by matching the `col2` values and return table `ft_test1` values.

Expected Output:

```
col2
------------
Dsouza mak Dee
John A Henry
```

Explaination about expected output:

1. The first record should display because of `mak` present in both table in `col2`
2. The second record is also present but with shuffling.

Try:

```
SELECT t1.col2
FROM ft_test1 t1
INNER JOIN ft_test2 t2
ON CONTAINS(t2.col2, t1.col2);
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Incorrect syntax near 't1'.

Comment: This is neither the semantics of [`CONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or the correct syntax. Probably you should use [`FREETEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/freetext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Also I think you will need to wrap the call in a multi statement TVF to allow it to use correlated parameters.

Comment: How will be -->  t2.col2 CONTAINS (t1.col2) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CONTAINS` doesn't do what you want. `FREETEXT` is closer and returns your desired results in this case.

You should check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/freetext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to see if the complete semantics are acceptable.

You would also need a helper TVF as below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION F1(@SearchText VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS @ft_test2 TABLE (
  col1 INT,
  col2 VARCHAR(max))
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @ft_test2
      SELECT *
      FROM   ft_test2 t2
      WHERE  FREETEXT (t2.col2, @SearchText)

      RETURN
  END

GO

SELECT t1.col2
FROM   ft_test1 t1
       CROSS APPLY F1(t1.col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ft_test2 to build a search term:

```
Declare @vals varchar(1000) = '';
Select @Vals = @Vals + Case When @Vals = '' Then '"'+col2+'"' Else ' OR ' + '"'+col2+'"' End
From ft_test2;

Select * From ft_test1  where FreeText(col2, @Vals);
```